# Error with using NSJsonSerialization: Invalid top-level type in JSON write

Tags: objective-c, nsjsonserialization

So I have a function that creates a dictionary like this and returns that dictionary-

```
- (NSDictionary *) createPostData{
    NSMutableDictionary * requestDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [requestDictionary setValue:@"type://someStuff" forKey: @"$type"];
    [requestDictionary setValue:@"account" forKey:@"Widget"];
    NSMutableDictionary* messageDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [messageDictionary setValue:@"type://someStuff" forKey:@"$type"];
    [messageDictionary setValue: self.password forKey:@"Password"];
    [messageDictionary setValue:false forKey:@"RememberMe"];
    [requestDictionary setValue:messageDictionary forKey:@"Message"];
    return requestDictionary;
}
```

I then  do this

```
 NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDataObject
                                                           options:0 // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                             error: &error];
```

And I get this error -

```
Error - *** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write
```

I can't really see why because I think I'm subscribing to the rules in the documentation - every key is a string, and I'm only using instances of NSDictionary and NSString.

What's going on?

Comment: Are you sure `postDataObject` is properly assigned the return value of the method you posted? Can you inspect it in the console and post the results here?

Comment: NSLog your dictionary going into dataWithJSONObject.  And note that setValue:false will cause premature termination of your inside dictionary.  It should be `setValue:@(false)`

Comment: `[messageDictionary setValue:false forKey:@"RememberMe"];` will remove the object for key `@"RememberMe"` from `messageDictionary`. If you actually want to set a value, use `@NO`.

Answer (score 2):

Set your block of code

```
      if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:postDataObject]) { NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDataObject
                                                       options:0 // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                         error: &error];}
```

instead of

```
       NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDataObject
                                                       options:0 // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                         error: &error];
```